# How to implement the following effects？The text color and the icon were changed after they were pressed

Tags: android

Here's the pics,the icon and the text color,and the background color changed .

[image]

When right layout is pressed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use selector for the background.

For the location you can use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation, and set weight for childs.

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2014/03/android-button-selector-tutorial-with.html#.Vt6dQuZRLuw

Here is an example how to reach it.

Good luck!